# Temporary failure in name resolution - Debian Book worm on Raspberry Pi (no network)

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi

Recently tried to assign static IP with wireless (wlan0) to my Raspberry pi with Debian Bookworm OS. After configuring interfaces file with static IP, IP is showing as assigned with the `hostname -I` command. But the Pi is not available on the wireless network and getting temporary failure in name resolution when trying to ping other servers or router.

Tried adding the name servers in `/etc/resolv.conf` file too. Getting same error. With the DHCP assigned IP everything works fine. What might be causing the issue with static IP?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the result of these commands? `ip link; ip -4 -br addr; ip route; ip -4 neigh` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you should be setting up a fixed IP address in the way you're going about it. In the 'bookworm' release, the RPi purveyors decided to replace `dhcpcd` with `NetworkManager`. Unless you're experienced in network configuration, you may be better off removing all the changes you've made so far, and use `nmcli` (part of `NetworkManager`) for the configuration.

If you've never used `nmcli`, you should be prepared; IMHO it is ponderous in comparison to `dhcpcd`. Read `man nmcli` before you start.

Let's begin - you'll need the "**NAME**"s of the interfaces to do the configuration. One way to get them is:

```bash
sudo nmcli -p connection show    # using my system for this

======================================
  NetworkManager connection profiles
======================================
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mesh01              b509f34f-8cec-4753-8024-62b59403303d  wifi      wlan0
lo                  d11f74e5-a19c-49a9-962f-402e2b88b7ae  loopback  lo
Wired connection 1  72c460ce-42c1-3585-9619-7ed3a8ee5a05  ethernet  --
```

For a static IP, you'll need to specify three (3) items: **1.)** IP addr, **2.)** DNS & **3.)** Gateway.

In your command use the **"NAME"** from the command above **as run on your system** (i.e. don't use `Mesh01`), and substitute an IP address appropriate for your network. Also know that `gateway` and `dns` addresses are not necessarily the same IP addr on your network:

```bash
sudo nmcli c mod "Mesh01" ipv4.addresses 192.168.1.201/24 ipv4.method manual
sudo nmcli con mod "Mesh01" ipv4.gateway 192.168.1.1
sudo nmcli con mod "Mesh01" ipv4.dns 192.168.1.1
```

And do not forget that applying a static IP addr, you are effectively saying to your DHCP client daemon, *"Stand down - I've got this"*. And so, having dismissed your DHCP daemon, you should be prepared to do the router/gateway/DHCP server configuration manually. Typically, that involves some manual configuration on those devices; e.g. ensuring that the static IP address you've assigned is outside of the "DHCP pool", etc.

Next, re-start the interface that you've configured above:

```bash
sudo nmcli c down "Mesh01"
sudo nmcli c up "Mesh01"
```

And that should do it. If you're still having problems, and you don't have a real need for a fixed IP, I suggest you let DHCP do its job. You can restore the DHCP functionality in your RPi as follows:

```bash
sudo nmcli con modify "Mesh01" ipv4.method auto
sudo nmcli c down "Mesh01"
sudo nmcli c up "Mesh01"
```